# swift - Converting String to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert a Date and Time String to NSDate with Swift, But the problem is The time is not converting perfectly, Even i set my Timezone correctly, Here's my code:

```
    var dateStr = "2015-10-16 08:00 AM"
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 28800)
    var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr)
    print(date!)
```

And it prints out like this: `2015-10-16 00:00:00 +0000` What do you think seems to be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong here. You should convert `date` to `String` before print it.

```
    let dateStr = "2015-10-16 08:00 AM"
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 28800)
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr)
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!))
```

or as in Swift 3

```
    let dateStr = "2015-10-16 08:00 AM"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 28800)
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

The same result: `2015-10-16 08:00 AM`